# What is the reason for the huge clutter of information in <style> inside the <head>?

Tags: html, styles

I'm an HTML beginner. I am seeing that many websites, even extremely simple ones, have a huge amount of style information inside the head, such as the code below (I've only copied about 10% of the actual style info. from one website).

**Questions:**

1. What is the reason for this clutter of information?
2. The "style" often seems to end with `{ display: none!important; }`
   `</style>`. Why is this "none!important" important?

   ```
   <style type="text/css">
       object[width="640"][height="160"],
       object[width="640"][height="100"],    
       embed[width="640"][height="160"],
       object[width="100"][height="100"],
       iframe[width="100%"][height="60"],
       object[width="300"][height="60"],
       object[width="200"][height="200"],
       object[width="1000"][height="250"],
       object[width="1000"][height="270"], 
       img[width="240"][height="400"], 

       #RightAdBlock, 
       .ad_head_rectangle, 
       object[width="300"][height="300"], 
       iframe[width="100%"][height="250"], 
       #ad_global_below_navbar, 
       #ad-background, 
       #AD_banner, 
       #AdColumn, 
       #AdContainer, 
       #AdHeader, 
       #AdImage, 
       #Adcode, 
       #AdvertiseFrame, 
       #Advertisements, 
       #BottomAdContainer, 
       . . . . . . iframe[src^="http://ad.yieldmanager.com/"], 
       #rhs_block > #mbEnd, 
       #tads.c { 
           display: none!important; 
       }
   </style>
   ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As declared by the **type** attribute in `type="text/css"` anything inside the style tag is CSS or [Cascading Style Sheets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS). CSS allows you to style your webpage with colors, spacing, fonts, etc...

This is one of the three basic "languages" you will need to develop a modern website:

1. **Html**: Content
2. **CSS**: Style
3. **JavaScript**: Logic

The reason that style tag looks like a mess is because normally you would find those styles in an entirely separate file. So basically you are seeing an entire file shoved into one line. This is sometimes done for performance reasons.

To answer your question about `{ display: none !important }`, `display: none` hides an element and `!important` is just a drastic measure to ensure that nothing can style it otherwise.

Comment: @mcmulins: Wow, thanks. As I said, I'm an HTML (and CSS, JScript, JQuery) beginner. In the little web development I've done so far I've tried to put some coding in separate CSS and JScript files.  Just so I clearly understand: You're saying some developers opt to put CSS-type style info.  directly into the HTML (index) file, yes? Also, regarding your "display: none hides an element " comment, how can I determine which element is being hidden?

Comment: By the way, the style info. I used in my example came from a website that only featured an image, nothing else. It's an image used "img src" line of the master website. Yet the image file had that tons of styling info. For something so simple, I wonder why. Maybe it was just stored there as somebody's placeholder and is style coding that gets recycling elsewhere.

Comment: @user3832452 I can't tell you exactly what they were selecting since parts of the styles are missing, but it looks like this is just a long comma separated list of elements that are all hidden. `object[width="640"][height="160"]`, `#RightAdBlock` and  `.ad_head_rectangle` are all just normal css selectors. It sounds like someone included an Ad on the page to get their revenue from the "view", and then hid it so the user wouldn't notice.

Comment: to clarify you would normally see a common separated list like `article, section { margin: 20px; }`. This would apply the margin to both `<article>` tags as well as `<section>` tags. The example you have given is just an extreme version of that where that list is hundreds of selectors long.